# How do I access A Subscription within a SubscriptionCollection without a loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-workflow

I have the following code which works:

```
ctx.load(workflowAssociations);

//below works but loops through all available workflows, it seems sub may contain the array that needs to be accessed

ctx.executeQueryAsync(function (sender, args) {

    var subsEnum = workflowAssociations.getEnumerator();

    while (subsEnum.moveNext()) {

        var sub = subsEnum.get_current();

        alert(sub);

        console.log('Web: ' + web.get_url() + ', Subscription: ' + 
          sub.get_name() + ', id: ' + sub.get_id());

        var initiationParams = {};
        workflowServicesManager.getWorkflowInstanceService().startWorkflowOnListItem(
          sub, items.getItemAtIndex(0).get_id(), initiationParams);

        ctx.executeQueryAsync(function (sender, args) {
            console.log('Workflow started.');
        }, errFunc);

    }

}, errFunc);


function errFunc(sender, args) {
alert("Error occured! " + args.get_message() + 
         '\r\nStack trace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

I am trying to simplify this loop and only access one object in the collection without the while loop. I have tried the following:

```
//var subsEnum = workflowAssociations.getEnumerator();
console.dir(subsEnum);
console.dir(workflowAssociations[2]);
console.log(subsEnum[2]);
var sub = subsEnum.get_current(0);
console.dir(sub);
console.dir(subsEnum);
```

However, most of these come up undefined. Here is an image of what it looks like when I explore the object using the watch expression ability in chrome.
I dont want to use that $2_0 thing because in migration I assume it may change.

I apologize in advance for any lack of information.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[`SP.Workflow.WorkflowAssociation` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245042.aspx) (`workflowAssociations` in your example) derives from [`SP.ClientObjectCollection` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff409279(v=office.14).aspx) which in addition to [`getEnumerator()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee659727(v=office.14).aspx) contains [some additional methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee553114(v=office.14).aspx) for accessing collection data such as:

- [`getItemAtIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee659517(v=office.14).aspx) - gets the element at the specified index of the `SP.ClientObjectCollection` class.
- `getData` - transforms `ClientObjectCollection` object to regular JavaScript array

**Examples**

*Enumerate collection*

```
var e = workflowAssociations.getEnumerator();
while(e.moveNext()){
    console.log(e.get_current().get_name()); //print Name of current WorkflowAssociation object     
}
```

*Get item at the specified index*

```
 var item = workflowAssociations.getItemAtIndex(0); //get first item
 console.log(item.get_name()); //print Name of WorkflowAssociation object
```

*Convert to array*

```
var items = workflowAssociations.get_data();
console.log(items[0].get_name()); //print Name of first WorkflowAssociation object
```